# Is a teaser with no image still a teaser?

Tags: interface-design, patterns, terminology

I usually expect a *teaser* to have some kind of multimedia content like an image or a video or an audio preview. Pretty much like a media-object .

But is a teaser still a *teaser*, if there's no multimedia content but only text & links?

Is that a *teaser without image*?
Or would generically rather be a *card*? (a block with a title and some content)

What's the correct naming/pattern?

Comment: A teaser for a book e.g. doesnt need any images, videos or audio.

Comment: He is not asking about video editing. He is asking about visual comunication, which is on topic here.

Comment: @BillyKerr Did you mean to post that comment on a different question? This question has nothing whatsoever to do with video editing…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - no, I saw "video" and "teaser" and apparently put two and two together and got five. Apologies.

Comment: To be fair, a "card" is a video term as well. I too thought it was about video, which it may be. But the heart of the question, to me, is more about marketing terminology than construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "teaser" is typically defined as **anything** which entices the viewer to look further (or keep watching in the case of multimedia) without actually giving away the "offer".

- Coming up! Do you want to save $500 a month?
- Later in the show - How you could save $500 a month!
- Inside: How you could save $500 a month!
- Could you use an extra $500 a month?
- What simple step could help you generate and extra $500 a month?

Teasers *don't need any image* to be effective.

[image]

I create teasers all the time for *envelopes* — which clearly don't contain any video or multimedia content.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick answer.

Text is can be an image.

A blank black image, is an image.

As a marketing effort just make sure that you can use that teasing later. If a black image is to later promote a "Black Adam" or a "Darkest Night" movie, then it has sense.

Even an empty space, on a bus stop with a small text can be, for example "This space is for you" a teaser.